Count reference values using a dynamic second table
I have the following challenge: Every week i receive an excel file with upcoming tasks (table1) and would like to add up the time required for all morning and evening tasks separately per day.
Table 1: Planned tasks for the week



Monday
Shift
Tuesday
Shift
Wednesday
Shift
Thursday
Shift
Friday
Shift




task 1
morning


task 5
evening














task 6
evening


task 5
morning
task 2
morning


task 1
evening








task 4
evening








task 6
evening









What i did so far is separately count the different tasks and multiply them each with the time value stored in table 2 in a hidden sheet.
Table 2: Required time per task



Task
Time




Task 1
1.0


Task 2
0.3


Task 3
0.8


Task 4
0.2


etc.
etc.



As the references in the formula are hardcoded this has the major drawback of me having to modify the formula every time for each day when a new task is added:
=SUM(COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$200;"task 1";$B$5;"morning") * Table2!$A$1 + SUM(COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$200;"task 2";$B$5;"morning") * Table2!$A$2 SUM(COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$200;"task 3";$B$5;"morning")*Table2!$A$3 + .....

What i would like to achieve is a dynamic lookup in table2 for the keyword and corresponding value. That way  the formula would no longer need to be modified and only keywords and times would need to be added to table2.
Unfortunately, I did not manage to find a suitable example of something comparable and didnt come up with something working myself (cannot use VBA or Python unfortunately).
I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how to do this (or tell me if it is not possible in excel).
I tried to use the MATCH function, but i honestly got really confused by the syntax.

If you have 365, this can be done with the newer functions:
=LET(
    d, taskTbl,
    tasks, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(d, 1), 2),
    morning, FILTER(tasks, CHOOSECOLS(tasks, 2) = "morning"),
    evening, FILTER(tasks, CHOOSECOLS(tasks, 2) = "evening"),
    morningTimes, XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(morning, 1), timeTbl[Task], timeTbl[Time], 0),
    eveTimes, XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(evening, 1), timeTbl[Task], timeTbl[Time], 0),
    VSTACK({"Morning Times", "Evening Time"}, HSTACK(SUM(morningTimes), SUM(eveTimes)))
)

I Name'd the first table taskTbl and the second timeTbl.  That way when you add tasks to either table, the formula will not have to be edited.
I have also assumed that your tables only include the single week.
For the table you show in your question, the result of this formula:

Note that tasks that do not exist in timeTbl will return 0 for the time so are not included in the totals.
Algorithm

Convert the table to a single column

Then WRAPROWS to create a two column table




Use the FILTER function to create two tables representing morning and evening

XLOOKUP to obtain the relevant times(note the zero's for those tasks that don't exist in your Table 2)

Return the sums of the morning and evening times separately

Note:
If you need to break it down into day of the week and hours for each shift, it becomes more complicated. You could extend the above algorithm to filter for each of those segments, but I would use Power Query as it will be easier to debug.
You don't show how you would want to format a report so below is a starting point.
To use Power Query, first select a cell in the timeTbl table and

Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range.
In the PQ UI: Close and Load To and select connection only.

Then select a cell in the taskTbl table.

Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see

let

//Read in the data
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="taskTbl"]}[Content],

//Create a List of all the column names
    colNames = Table.ColumnNames(Source),

//Split the table so as to create a list of Records
//  containing information as to Day, Task And shift
    #"Split Days" = 
        List.Combine(
            List.Accumulate(
                List.Numbers(0,5,2),
                {},
                (s,c)=> s & 
                    {List.Transform(
                        List.Transform(
                            List.Select(
                                List.Zip(Table.ToColumns(Table.SelectColumns(Source,List.Range(colNames,c,2)))), 
                            each List.NonNullCount(_)>0), 
                        each List.Combine({{colNames{c}}, _})),
                each Record.FromList(_,{"Day","Task","Shift"}))
                })),
            
//Convert the records to a Table
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(#"Split Days", Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"Day", "Task", "Shift"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Column",{{"Day", type text}, {"Task", type text}, {"Shift", type text}}),

//Add the relevant times for each Task referring to the timeTble Table
    #"Add Time" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Time", (r)=> 
        Table.SelectRows(timeTbl, each Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase(r[Task],[Task])=0)[Time]{0}?, type nullable number),

//Group by Day and Shift and Sum the times
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Add Time", {"Day", "Shift"}, {
        {"Time", each List.Sum([Time])??0, type nullable number}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"

Results

Of course, if you prefer an output like:

some minor code changes could easily be accomplished.
In this table, the blanks represent shifts with no tasks at all.

Thank you very much for your extensive explanation - now i get the concept of the LET function! I managed to get it working using the modified code [code]=LET(
tasks; A5:B10;
shift; FILTER(tasks; CHOOSECOLS(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(tasks); 2);2) = "morning");
shiftTime; XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(shift; 1); timeTbl[Task]; timeTbl[Time]; 0);
SUM(shiftTime)
)[code] I will have a look into the PowerQuery out as well, but i think this will be sufficient already! Thank you

With Microsoft 365,

Adjust data range tbShifts, A1:J6 to include future entries - for example A1:J1000
Get unique shifts in uShifts
Get shift total for each day 'block' with column numbers: task_cols, INDEX(tbShifts,,task_col) and INDEX(tbShifts,,task_col + 1)

=LET(
    tbShifts, A1:J6,
    num_days, COLUMNS(tbShifts) / 2,
    task_cols, SEQUENCE(num_days, , 1, 2),
    uShifts, UNIQUE(TOCOL(DROP(CHOOSECOLS(tbShifts, task_cols + 1), 1), 1)),
    day_totals, LAMBDA(acc, day_num,
        LET(
            task_col, INDEX(task_cols, day_num, 1),
            day_name, INDEX(tbShifts, 1, task_col),
            shift_total, LAMBDA(s,
                SUM(
                    XLOOKUP(
                        FILTER(
                            INDEX(tbShifts, , task_col),
                            INDEX(tbShifts, , task_col + 1) = s,
                            ""
                        ),
                        tbTaskTime[Task],
                        tbTaskTime[Time],
                        0
                    )
                )
            ),
            VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(day_name, TOROW(MAP(uShifts, shift_total))))
        )
    ),
    REDUCE(HSTACK("Day", TOROW(uShifts)), SEQUENCE(num_days), day_totals)
)



Thank you! Thats also a great idea! I got it working with the solution above, but will try yours as well!
